# como limpiar mi div de modo que mi array no se repita

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io, websocket

hola como puedo limpiar mi div, de modo de que cuando que el array users. no me repita el código

```
    function updateUsers(socket){   
    socket.on('updateUsers',function(data){       
        let usuarios = document.querySelector('#usuarios');
        for(let i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++){
            let us = `<div id ="user">` +data.users[i] +`</div>`;
            usuarios.innerHTML += us;
            console.log(data.users[i]);
        }
        
        
    });

}
```

Comment: Puedes poner `usuarios.innerHTML='';` antes del bucle for. Pero ojo, estás repitiendo el id `#user`. Los id deben ser únicos en un documento. Puedes usar `class` si sólo quieres darle estilo

Comment: donde estoy repitiendo el id #user me puedes mostrar un ejemplo porfavor quiero que el arreglo users no me repita los nombres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estás explicando en qué consiste la repetición que quieres evitar.

Revisando qué ocurre en un par de escenarios, supongamos que invocas la función una vez. Con eso el listener queda declarado y reaccionará a las actualizaciones futuras. La primera vez que el socket manda una actualización, por ejemplo

```
data = {
  users: ['pedro', 'juan']
}
```

se llena el div, quedando:

```
<div id="usuarios">
   <div id="user">pedro</div>
   <div id="user">juan</div>
</div>
```

Ahí ya hay un error, formalmente hablando. Tienes varios id #user. Podrías interpolar el contenido del índice `i`, o el valor de `data.users[i]` para generar un identificador único, si realmente necesitas un id.

```
 for(let i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++){
        let us = `<div id ="user_${i}">${data.users[i]}</div>`;
        usuarios.innerHTML += us;
        console.log(data.users[i]);
    }
```

Segundo, imagino que tú sabes el formato de los items del array `users`, que no vendrá por ejemplo un objeto entre medio de los strings.

---

Cuando el socket mande una nueva actualización, que podría ser

```
data = {
  users: ['juan', 'diego']
}
```

Se repetirán los elementos que ya hayas recibido, quedando

```
<div id="usuarios">
   <div id="user">pedro</div>
   <div id="user">juan</div>
   <div id="user">juan</div>
   <div id="user">diego</div>
</div>
```

Si esta es la repetición que quieres evitar, podrías limpiar el contenedor antes del bucle

```
   usuarios.innerHTML = '';
   for(let i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++){
        let us = `<div id ="user_${i}">${data.users[i]}</div>`;
        usuarios.innerHTML += us;
        console.log(data.users[i]);
    }
```

---

Por otro lado, puede que la repetición a la que te refieres ocurra porque invocas dos veces (o más) la *función* `updateUsers`. Cada vez que la invocas se declara un nuevo listener que existe junto a los anteriores. Declarar dos listeners provocará que el *evento* gatille ambos listeners.

Una manera de evitar esta situación sería fijar una propiedad en el objeto *socket* que señale que el listener ya ha sido declarado, en cuyo caso no corresponde declarar otro más.

```
function updateUsers(socket){   
    if(socket.listenerDeclared) {
      return;
    }
    socket.on('updateUsers',function(data){
        // ....
    }
    socket.listenerDeclared = true;
}
```